# Calling a function in a sibling self-executing function

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

So, I'm trying to call a function from another function that doesn't share the same scope.

As you can see, we have the jQuery function and then the callback function that is calling it. I should also note that Swiper is a touch slider, but I'm not sure it's relevant in this case, because I want to understand theoretically how I can call a function that sits within an anonymous function.

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var productPageSwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
    spaceBetween: 10,
    centeredSlides: true
  });
});

var callback = function(){
  productPageSwiper.slideTo(3);
}

callback();
```

Comment: you need `productPageSwiper` to be global perhaps

Comment: Is there a reason that `callback` shouldn't be declared inside of your jQuery load call?

Comment: Actually, if I include it within the load call everything works, but I'm trying to understand how to make it work if I decouple the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make `productPageSwiper` accessible to both functions by increasing it's scope, that will work.

```
jQuery(function($) {
  window.productPageSwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
    spaceBetween: 10,
    centeredSlides: true
  });
});

var callback = function(){
  window.productPageSwiper.slideTo(3);
}

callback();
```

Or to avoid polluting the global scope:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  productPageSwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
    spaceBetween: 10,
    centeredSlides: true
  });
});

var callback = function(swiper) {
  swiper.slideTo(3);
}

callback(productPageSwiper);
```

Comment: I'm new to coding so forgive me if this is a dumb question, but doesn't that just pollute the global namespace? Is there a way to actually reference the jQuery function?

Comment: You're correct - it does pollute the global namespace. Personally, I would restructure the JavaScript to that the function and callback shared the same scope, or pass the swiper instance as an argument to the callback.

Comment: Passing the swiper instance as an argument is something I didn't think of. Is it something along the lines of this [codepen](http://codepen.io/modermo/pen/ZeMRyR)?

Comment: Ah! I see! Isn't `productPageSwiper` still inaccessible globally though because it's contained with the load call?

Comment: Yes. I was just suggesting how I would approach the problem to prevent polluting the global scope. Can you post more code to actually show where you're using the callback? And if your problem isn't resolved, perhaps mark the question as unanswered so that others may be more inclined to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139188/discussion-between-modermo-and-rob).